# QGIS - Can't clip two shapefile

Tags: qgis, clip, geoprocessing

I have been trying to clip two shapefiles for a few days now, and no matter what I do, I get this message:

> GEOS geoprocessing error: intersection failed. - Execution failed after ... seconds

This is what I've done so far:

- Check validity - both shapefile comes with nothing in the "invalid output" and "error output"
- I've fixed the geometry on both shapefile
- I've created a spatial index for both shapefile
- If I try to clip with a smaller part of my overlay layer and it works, so I've tried to reduce the extent of my overlay layer so it is no more than what is showing on the layout, but it still doesn't work. When doing this, the "loading bar" goes up to 5-7% and then stops.

I'm clipping using Vector -> Geoprocessing -> Clip

I'm not sure what's not working here and I'm wondering how I can fix this.

Comment: Have you tried checking validity by selecting the QGIS method? do you have a sample data that fails you can provide?

Comment: do your two layers have the same projection?

Comment: @IanTurton yes they have the same projection

Comment: @LouisCottereau not sure what you mean by the QGIS method, so far I have used the "check validity" tool from QGIS. Happy to share my shapefiles with you, but I'm quite new to this forum and I don't know how

Comment: "Check validity" tool has two modes : 'GEOS' and 'QGIS' usually the 'QGIS' mode catches additional problems with geometries that may or may not cause your issue. As for providing the data you could provide either a dropbox-like link to the zipped shapefiles or if you only have a couple of geometries then directly in wkt format.

Comment: @LouisCottereau I have tried to use the QGIS mode and a few errors came out. I have spend a bit of time cleaning up the file until I have no more error when running check validity, but I still can't get the two files to clip. Here a a link to download the shapefile, I have named them input and overlay for clarity: [link](https://we.tl/t-TXPQtZZBBR)